# Can i change app logos and colors based on customer type?

Tags: android

let's suppose that customer A wants his app to be blue, while user B wants his app to be red, both app, are the same in execution, except for the colors and image logos. So, to change the app's colors based on customer login would be a violation of googles terms ?

Comment: A violation of terms? I can't think of any way that a colour change could violate any terms, why do you think it might?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make in `values` folder a `themes.xml` file (like `styles.xml`)
There you can define 2 or more themes with colors that can you set later in your app for some type of user:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.White" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        ...
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Black" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
        ...
    </style>
</resources>
```

Set in your `AndroidManifest.xml` your theme in each `activity` that should be affected:

```
...
<activity android:name="com.example.YourApp.MainActivity"
            ...
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.White"/>
            ...
```

Make a class for saving the `states`, called `Utility.class`:

```
public class Utility {

    public static void setTheme(Context context, int theme) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        prefs.edit().putInt(context.getString(R.string.prefs_theme_key), theme).apply();
    }

    public static int getTheme(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return prefs.getInt(context.getString(R.string.prefs_theme_key), 1);
    }
}
```

And in your `TargetActivity.class` you will set the method to apply the `states` with your specific user type:

```
public void updateTheme() {
        if (Utility.getTheme(getApplicationContext()) <= 1) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_White);
        } else if (Utility.getTheme(getApplicationContext()) == 2) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Black);
        }
    }
```

To set the saved `theme` at start of the app just type that into your `MainActivity.class`:

```
private final static int THEME_WHITE = 1;
private final static int THEME_BLACK = 2;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        updateTheme();
    }


public void updateTheme() {
        if (Utility.getTheme(getApplicationContext()) <= THEME_WHITE) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_White);
        } else if (Utility.getTheme(getApplicationContext()) == THEME_BLACK) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Black);
        }
    }
```

That's how you work with different `Themes`. I think your question is answered by now :)

PS: Setting different colors for users isn't a violation against the terms of google. Google itself gave each letter a different color. ;)